# 'ScriptManager' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.Web.UI'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

'ScriptManager' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.Web.UI'

Hi, i just converted an old app ASP. Net VB and i have 23 errors with the same

What could it be?

If you need more details please tell me

Comment: possible duplicate of [The type 'System.Web.UI.ScriptManager' is ambiguous: it could come from assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294485/the-type-system-web-ui-scriptmanager-is-ambiguous-it-could-come-from-assembly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means there are 2 imported namespaces with the same class, fully qualify the object name and your good.

Comment: How or where do i do that?

Comment: Not sure, but you did upgrade, more namespaces were made available and then it was confused as to know which object you were asking for. There are two `ScriptManager` objects from diff namespaces.